# AngularJS with Karma Unknown provider: $routeProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine

I'm getting the well-documented error below trying to run an Angular.js app through Karma:

```
[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeProvider
```

The JS is actually generated from ClojureScrpit using purnam. But looking at the generated JS, it looks ok:

```
var news = {app:{}};
news.app.newsApp = angular.module("newsApp", ["ngRoute"]);
angular.module("newsApp").config(["$routeProvider", function(a) {
  a.when("/", {templateUrl:"views/main.html", controller:"MainCtrl"});
  a.otherwise({redirectTo:"/"});
  return a;
}]);
```

So I am passing in 'ngRoute', which looks to be the common cause. My karma.conf.js includes angular-route:

```
files: [
  'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
  'app/scripts/*.js',
  'app/scripts/**/*.js',
  'test/mock/**/*.js',
  'test/spec/**/*.js'
],
```

And I see the angular-route loading in karma startup. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work at:

http://plnkr.co/edit/9xEZm0z22ab2YL6kL1fT?p=preview

```
var news = {app:{}};

news.app.newsApp = angular.module("newsApp", ["ngRoute"]);

news.app.newsApp.config(["$routeProvider", function(a) {
  a.when("/", {templateUrl:"views/main.html", controller:"MainCtrl"})
  a.otherwise({redirectTo:"/"});
  return a;
}]);
```

Comment: Indeed it does. It looks like there was some conflict in the generated code fro ClojureScript, due to using an outdated version of purnam. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Here is another try!

```
angular.module('newsApp').config(['$configName', '$routeProvider', function newsAppConfig(config, $routeProvider) {}]);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The module is being defined correctly on the line above your proposed change, then just referenced on the line that `config` is called.

Comment: Try $route instead of $routeProvider

Comment: I just tried $route, but oddly I get the exact same error about $routeProvider. I have triple checked that the source file no longer refers to $routeProvider

Comment: What about like this: 

news.app.newsApp("newsApp", ["ngRoute"]).config(["$routeProvider", function(a) {
  a.when("/", {templateUrl:"views/main.html", controller:"MainCtrl"});
  a.otherwise({redirectTo:"/"});
  return a;
}]);

Comment: Yes. I tried that as well, just in case. Same result I'm afraid

Comment: I've edited above, seems you are missing the cfg target/name.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this was my solution. As you can see in the file karma.conf.js the javascript array named 'files[]' includes the folder /test/mock/**/*js.
You can add in the folder 'mock' a file called modules.js.
In this file add the following line;

```
'use strict';
 angular.mock.module('ngRoute', []);
```

So the line angular.mock.module('ngRoute', []); should do the trick. add more modules to mock in this file if necessary.